# Comparison of boiling points of para-derivatives of phenol

Tags: organic-chemistry, boiling-point, phenols, physical-organic-chemistry

The boiling points of four para-derivatives of phenol are:

[image]

How can we compare the boiling points of *p*-nitrophenol and *p*-aminophenol?

Apart from the hydroxyl group, *p*-nitrophenol has two oxygen atoms to form inter-molecular H-bonding. Whereas, *p*-aminophenol has a nitrogen atom and two hydrogen atoms to form inter-molecular H-bonding. Also, the molecular mass of *p*-nitrophenol is more than that of *p*-aminophenol.

Comment: what kind of bonds break during the change of state?

Comment: @Nicolas As far as boiling point is concerned, our interest is limited to various inter-molecular forces between molecules, which will reduce in phase conversion from liquid to gas.

Comment: And what kind of intermolecular bonding are possible in p-aminophenol but which is not possible in p-nitrophenol?

Comment: Whatever consideration, note that the difference is just 5 °C.

Comment: @Nicolas I can't think of any. Out of these two, which one has higher dipole moment?

Comment: Such comparison hardly makes sense - apples vs oranges.